# could not create the Java Virtual Machine while running tomcat

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, xampp, startup

i have a presentation about hibernate and to do an example i needed tomcat
after installing tomcat 10 i tried to start it up using this command `C:\tomcat\bin>startup`
below is the result I get when i run it

```
C:\tomcat\bin>startup
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\tomcat"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\tomcat"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\tomcat\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_361"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\tomcat\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\tomcat\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Using CATALINA_OPTS:   ""
```

but window pops up for a split of a second and goes away.

so i tried the following command to see what's going on `C:\tomcat\bin>catalina.bat run`
here is the results

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\tomcat"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\tomcat"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\tomcat\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_361"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\tomcat\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\tomcat\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Using CATALINA_OPTS:   ""
Unrecognized option: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

btw here are the envirment variables .. because i saw many trying having the problem there .. but i dont think it's my case
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqaQD.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhgxL.png)

*N.B.*
tomcat version 10.1.7
JDK 17
jre-8u361

i had many problem before this that i tried to solve, some of them did and some not , always a problem leads me to another , i used to have error 500 Internal Server Error aloot while trying to follow a tutorial.

i dont know if this may be a help or not but i used to have another problem that i think i already solved which is i had xampp running tomcat too , meaning i had an old version on xampp and i instaled a new one, then i deleted the new one and replace new tomcat version instead in xampp, and deleted the service so it can be created from new ;

**but after all nothing succeded so i uninstalled xampp, tomcat and java , and started from new.
**

Comment: i just checket the services .. i did not find any service called tomcat or apache tomcat at all  :(

Comment: That Tomcat instance definitely uses Java 8 not Java 17. Buz ```--add-opens``` option introduced in Java 9. Force Tomcat use newer Java version

Comment: i installed the service using `service.bat install` but still same problem no changes

Comment: i deleted JRE_HOME so that way it will be only JAVA_HOME variable
and it worked now it's open 
i will move on now with my code .. see you when a new problem apear lol

Comment: Then don't affraid to vote and accept the answer.

Comment: Tomcat 10 requires Java 11 or later: https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, Tomcat using Java 8 version which does not support `--add-opens` option. This option introduced in Java 9.

**Update**
Thanks to Olaf's comment I redefine the previous sentence. However Tomcat 10.0.x used to support Java 8 it was dropped in 10.1.0 which requires Java 11 at least.

A Java Runtime Environment required by Apache Tomcat. Older Java versions shipped multiple artifacts JRE only and JDK. For now it had changed.
When Tomcat starts it will try to evaulate installed runtime environment based on environment variables.

If `JRE_HOME` is **set** then it will be used.
If `JRE_HOME` is **not set** but `JAVA_HOME` **is set** then Tomcat startup script will automatically set `JRE_HOME` based on `JAVA_HOME` vaule.
If both `JRE_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME` **is set** then `JRE_HOME` will be used.

As the question describes both environment variable is set, so `JRE_HOME` will be used. But `JRE_HOME` points to Java 8.

You can customize `JRE_HOME` (set to new Java version) or you also can remove this environment variable and use `JAVA_HOME` as I described previously.

Comment: It's not that it's an _old_ java8. It's because no Java 8 (no matter how new) is compatible with tomcat 10: https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Comment: @OlafKock thanks the feedback. More precisely 10.0.x supports Java 8 but 10.1.x requires Java 11 or later. Unfortunately I cannot update the answer, I will try it later. Tanks again.

Comment: Well, 10.0 [is gone by now](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-eol.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have just changed the(Server shutdown="SHUTDOWN" port="8090") of server.xml in apache-tomcat-9.0.41

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was removing `JRE_HOME` environment variable and simply leaving the `JAVA_HOME` variable which is the path to my JDK installation directory. This should be the number one answer.